# Python - Changing the case sensitivity of specific words in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, case-sensitive

I have the following lists:

```py
mylist = ["FOO", "BAR", "NOTFOO", "NOTBAR"]

mylist2 = ["Foo", "Bar"]
```

I want to replace words in mylist which exist in mylist2, but as uppercase.
my desired output would look like:

```py
mylist = ["Foo", "Bar", "NOTFOO", "NOTBAR"]
```

I tried the following. However there was no change in mylist.

```py
for word in mylist:
    for word2 in mylist2:
        if word == word2.upper():
            word.replace(word, word2)
```

Comment: Are the elements in mylist guaranteed to be capitalized already? (You wrote uppercase, but I think actually meant capitalized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python's `for item in somelist` syntax, `item` is essentially set to a **copy** of each element in the list on each iteration, rather than a reference to anelement in the list.

You also don't really need the inner loop, since Python's `in` condition can be used to check for list membership.

And also note it looks like you want the replaced items capitalized, not all-uppercase.

I think a relatively Pythonic way to accomplish what you want is:

```py
for i, word in enumerate(mylist):
  if word.capitalize() in mylist2:
    mylist[i] = word.capitalize()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for index,word in enumerate(mylist):
    for word2 in mylist2:
        if word == word2.upper():
            mylist[index] = word2
```

**Output**
print(mylist)

```
['Foo', 'Bar', 'NOTFOO', 'NOTBAR']
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine:

```
mylist = ["FOO", "BAR", "NOTFOO", "NOTBAR"]
mylist2 = ["Foo", "Bar"]


for x in range(0, len(mylist)): 

    for word2 in mylist2:
        if mylist[x] == word2.upper():
            mylist[x] = word2

print(str(mylist))
```